# Invalid hash key of facebook login after published play store in android

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-login

I am getting this error is given below of image...

[image]

How to solve this issue. Normally working Facebook login but after published play store cannot work Facebook login. Please help me.

Comment: you didn't attach the image correctly. Always recheck when you post

Comment: @Aminah Nuraini,still now show the image please solve my problem..